# Drupal 7 and Addthis

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, addthis

So I need to use addthis. Please visit my page which I am trying to implement add this.

http://www.iamvishal.com/dev/node/13

The add this buttons won't show up on my page. I am able to implement it using plain html code but the drupal implementation is not working.

The js is getting loaded but I am unable to debug the problem as I am unable to find the problem why this is happening.

cheers,
Vishal

p.s - for more on addthis pls visit http://www.addthis.com/

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.slider = {
        attach:function(context) {
            var script = 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#domready=1';
            if (window.addthis) {
                window.addthis = null;
            }
            $.getScript(script);
        }

    };

}(jQuery));
</script>



<div id="sociallinks">
<div class="viewing">Request a viewing</div>


<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>

<!-- AddThis Button END -->
</div><!-- end of social links -->
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in D7 was to create a new 'text format' where there were *no* filters enabled.  For whatever reason D7 thinks that the AddThis code is faulty or incomplete.

configuration > content authoring > text formats > add text format

Give it a shot.

Comment: and how do I then relate this text format to the addthis script ? Should I just keep it as default ?